Mechanism for haloalkane reduction through different classes of reductive reagents
I've been studying the reduction of "haloalkanes" $(\ce{R-X})$ to "alkanes" $(\ce{R-H})$ and upon reviewing the reagents present in the reaction, I could primarily identify two types of reductive reagents: "Metal Hydrides" (e.g., $\ce{LiAlH4}$) and "Metals alongside H giving species" (e.g., $\ce{Mg + H2O}$).  I've not included other types such as $\ce{H2 + Pd/Pt/Ni}$ or $\ce{Na + C2H5OH}$.
For the former class of reagents, I reviewed material online and found out research papers pointing out that they follow a "free radical" (or electron transfer) mechanism that works by the reaction of an alkyl radical $\ce{R^.}$ with $\ce{H^.}$ (formed from the metal hydride). [1][2]
The problem arises for the later class of reagents for which I have doubts about. If we react a haloalkane $\ce{R-X}$ with $\ce{Mg + H2O}$, it would produce a Grignard reagent as expected. Although, as we know its formation would include a step producing a radical $\ce{R^.}$. [3]
Now, my doubt is that which one out of the following two cases will most likely lead to the formation of the alkane $\ce{R-H}$ (hence, being the correct mechanism)?

Carbanion $\ce{R^{-}}$ in Grignard reagent reacts with $\ce{H^{+}}$ in $\ce{H2O}$

Intermediate radical $\ce{R^.}$ forming $\ce{H^.}$ and reacting with it (as done by the former class of reagents)


Furthermore, would the same mechanism be observed in other reagents of the "same class" (e.g. $\ce{Zn + HCl}$) since they too can form an organometallic compound that can give a $\ce{R^{-}}$ and a $\ce{R^{•}}$ during its formation?

The formation as mentioned in (1) seems counterintuitive since I read on ChemSE that Grignard Reagents do not produce "free carbanions", which would be the species reacting with $\ce{H^{+}}$.

This makes me speculate if the Grignard reagent could break up into $\ce{R^.}$ instead of $\ce{R^{-}}$, thus proceeding with (2) instead. I could not find anything related to this during my research.



Note: I've read posts on ChemSE (here and here) talking about the same topic although they fail to provide a reasoning for the respective mechanisms mentioned.

The former post explains the mechanism through the "insertion" of the metal $\ce{M}$ in the haloalkane $\ce{R-X}$ to form an organometallic compound which reacts with $\ce{H^{+}}$ extracted from $\ce{H2O}$ to form the alkane $\ce{R-H}$ via $\ce{R^{-}}$, disregarding the possibility of formation through the radical $\ce{R^.}$ (for both $\ce{Mg}$ and $\ce{Zn}$).

Conversely, the later post explains the mechanism through the propagation of $\ce{H^.}$, which forms a $\ce{R^.}$ and then reacts with it to form the alkane (completely different from the $\ce{R^{-}}$ or $\ce{R^.}$ approaches mentioned above). Now, is this mechanism completely wrong or is it actually the correct one? (I believe this mechanism could instead explain the other class of reductive reagents I excluded, namely $\ce{H2 + Pd/Pt/Ni}$, Metals, and Metals with $\ce{C2H5OH}$ or liq. $\ce{NH3}$ etc.)



References:

Lawrence W. Menapace and Henry G. Kuivila, "Mechanism of Reduction of Alkyl Halides by Organotin Hydrides," J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1964, 86(15), 3047–3051 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01069a015).
Edward C. Ashby, R. N. DePriest, A. B. Goel, B. Wenderoth, and T. N. Pham, "Occurrence of electron transfer in the reduction of organic halides by lithium aluminum hydride and aluminum hydride," J. Org. Chem. 1984, 49(19), 3545–3556 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00193a019).


Well thought out question +1.

I have usually seen the conversion of alkyl halides to alkanes using Grignard reagents as a two step process. React with Mg in ether/THF, then react with water—not altogether. Is there a reference you could provide for the Mg + water reaction system?

@Sonder Sir through the Mg + water reaction system I did mean the standard scheme of Grignard reagent formation i.e. Mg in ether/THF and then reaction with water. (I omitted ether/THF since the question mainly focused on the radical and carbanion)
